# Google Analytics says "Tracking Not Installed" but I see it working?

Tags: google-analytics

My site www.katievb.com is a blog hosted by blogspot.com.  I've created a Google Analytics account and registered a "Universal Analytics" property.  It provided a unique UA ID and some code to embed in the HTML that looks similar to this:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'katievb.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I did this probably about 24 hours ago.  The GA admin page has said "Status: Tracking Not Installed" this whole time.  However, GA Real-Time actually does track my visits.  (I can use Firefox on a Mac and in real-time see that on the Analytics screen, and then I can go over to a Windows computer with Chrome and visit katievb.com and see that on the real-time screen too.)

In blogspot's settings, I intentionally did NOT populate the Settings > Other > Analytics Web Property ID because it appeared to me that that would expect that I was using the old-style Google Analytics (ga.js) and not this new kind (analytics.js).

Also, I then replicated this in a completely independent pair of blogspot/GA accounts.

Why does it say "Tracking Not Installed"?  It seems to be tracking, and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to change about how I installed it.

I've read the instructions many times and have tried different versions of their code and placing it in different locations, such as prior to `</head>` or `</body>`.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution for this I am also seeing Real time events but have the status Tracking Not Installed but I have no events recorded i'm not sure if there is just a lag in them being recorded - i implemented new code yesterday

Comment: It eventually worked (with no changes by me).

Comment: maybe i just need to be patient then thank you

Comment: Also keep in mind that browser extensions (such as AdBlock) can affect behavior.  For example, I recently installed analytics.js on a website and the dash was saying "Tracking Not Installed", and when I visited my page, I saw 0 users in Real Time.  But then I opened an Incognito tab in Chrome (so that I had no extensions interfering) and visited my page, and I saw 1 user in Real Time (me).  One way you can know that something is wrong is: use Developer Tools > Network tab. See if analytics.js says "(pending)" in the Status column. Instead it should say "304 Not Modified".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Eventually it started working.  I think it took a day or 2 for the status to accurately reflect that tracking had been properly installed.  It's bizarre... because Real-time was working, so I would have guessed that Google's status code would have been able to be updated real-time too.

Comment: but what if i have Status: Tracking Not Installed ? should i wait for the 48 hours ?

Answer (score 12):

It takes up to 72 hours to detect, but look in the Reporting section, Standard Reports, under Real Time, and it should show at least 1 active visitors on the site, which is probably you.

Answer (score 9):

**You can access to real time tracking**.

[To see Real-Time data, navigate to the Reporting tab and select Real-Time from the left hand report navigation column.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en)

You will **see 1 visitor** if there were 1 visitor **within the last minute**.

[image: screenshot of the realtime view]

Comment: This is not helpful and doesn't answer any of the questions.

Comment: I have a site that shows up in realtime, but for all 6 months it continues saying that "tracking not installed". So having realtime reports isn't a guarantee of fixing the poster's problem.

Comment: @EugeneBujak Maybe it is related what I read [here](https://class.coursera.org/startup-001/assignment/view?assignment_id=12): The tricky part is that if you only use analytics.js and don't also use ga.js, the Analytics Admin page won't say 'Tracking Installed'. This is a bug on Google's end in terms of their documentation. You can debug your setup with this Google link: Verify your web tracking setup, though things should work if you followed the above instructions.

Comment: “should work” doesn’t mean it will always work and in my understanding OP is asking “what went wrong”. Answer was not provided. I doubt anyone outside Google can provide that, though.

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP already mentioned that Real Time tracking was working for him. Telling him how to check his Real Time page doesn't answer his question.

Comment: Actually I don't remember @Shivam. I think I was trying to find a solution to check if Google Analytics was working, and I didn't read the question carefully. It seems there are lots of more people like me, so this answer is very useful for them. If you are in a rush and just read _Google Analytics says “Tracking Not Installed” but I see it working?_, this answer is perfect.