# Google Analytics not reporting and status is "Tracking Not Installed" but 'Real Time' monitor is still reporting

Tags: google-analytics

I seem to be having some trouble with having GA report activity. I've created a property and added the script right above the end head tag on my site, but GA doesn't seem to be reporting any activity... Although, the "Real Time" feature is showing me that I am currently on my website when I am on it. The status says "Tracking Not Installed" but I did install it. The most confusing thing of all is that 'Real Time' is working but nothing else.

Help me out?

Comment: Please note that this forum is for coding questions only. You can post this to Webmasters instead. However, it usually takes up to 24 hours for data to be processed into your standard reports, if you had just installed the GA tracking code on your site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Analytics says "Tracking Not Installed" but I see it working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952379/google-analytics-says-tracking-not-installed-but-i-see-it-working)